# Mocking static method call with Powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I need to write a unit test case for a method, present in Utilities.java, which does

```
  client = ABCClient.Factory.newInstance(connectionProperties);
```

Here is what I did in my test case

```
@PrepareForTest({ABCClient.class,ABCClient.Factory.class})
@Test
public void testGetABCClient() throws Exception
{
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(ABCClient.class);
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(ABCClient.Factory.class);

  PowerMockito.when(ABCClient.Factory.newInstance(any(Properties.class)))
      .thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
  try
  {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    idpsUtilities.getABCClient(p);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

I get this error

> org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException:
>
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@448ff1a8 The class ABCClient not prepared for
>   test.

What did I do wrong?

Here is my pom

```
<properties>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<spring-cloud.version>Edgware.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
<spring-boot.version>1.5.9.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
<packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
<hystrix.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</hystrix.version>
<powermock.version>1.7.1</powermock.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
<artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
<version>${powermock.version}</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
<artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
<version>${powermock.version}</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
<version>2.7.5</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: The *static access* is a **design problem**. It makes the code hard to reuse and hard to maintain. You problem testing it is a clear sign of that problem. So instead surrendering to you bad design by using PowerMock you should use *dependency injection* to pass along the `ABCClient.Factory.newInstance()` object from the outside into your code under test so that is can be easily replaces by a regular mock.

Comment: Problem is I am using other team's code to get the instance. I have to pass the properties to get the instance.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Dependency Injection is just as bad, if not worse, than static factories; they both lead to anti-OO code.

Comment: @Rogério Do you have any resource supporting your statement?

Comment: @Pretty but the *code under test* is your own?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle No, just my extensive real-world experience. But if you look at any DI example online, it's easy to see that injected dependencies are always *stateless* classes - they are not objects. DI-based codebases typically display a clear separation between "value objects" (usually persistent Entities) and "service objects", none of which are true objects - in fact, such codebases tend to be highly procedural in style.

Comment: @Rogério *"just my extensive real-world experience"* Then it stands against *my* extensive real world experiences as well as of [Robert C "uncle Bob" Martin](https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) and [Roy Osherove](https://www.amazon.com/Art-Unit-Testing-examples/dp/1617290890) to name two others...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Well, I didn't just mention my experience. You lost the opportunity to say something actually relevant, such as how using DI actually promote better design over just using objects, or even over using static factories or "Service Locators" as named by [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), the author who coined "Dependency Injection" and described its proper usage as a way to "separate use from configuration".

Comment: yes, this test code is mine but the classes having static methods aren't.

Comment: @Pretty then you could call those static methods *before* the constructor of your code and pass the instance along...

Comment: do you mean in @BeforeMethod?